# ¿Como mostrar el tiempo en el que se hizo una acción?

Tags: post, datetime, time

Queria preguntar como hacer para mostrar el tiempo en el que se hizo un **posteo**, por ejemplo **"Esta publicación se hizo hace 2hs"**. Yo cuando mandas un posteo guardo un `time()` en la misma tabla en la que se guarda el "titulo" "contenido" etc... pero el numero que me guarda en la bd como lo puedo usar para mostrar eso que quiero? la pagina es: **www.gholes.net**

trato de hacer una especie de resta, la verdad no se como hacerlo.

Comment: Hola Juan, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español. Completa el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para aprender más sobre el funcionamiento del sitio (y ganar así una medalla). Deberías editar la pregunta para añadir algo de código (lo que hayas intentado) y una descripción detallada de los errores y dificultades que te estés encontrando. Lee [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para más información y recomendaciones.

Comment: @LeviArista igual te viene bien este enlace: [¿Conoces los magic-links para los comentarios? Aprende a usarlos](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1058/15855) ^^

Comment: @lois6b Hey!, muchas gracias, lo tendré en cuenta.